# compare time.time() & System.Currenttimemillis()

Tags: java, python, timestamp

I am working on multiple projects in python and java. I have a timestamp from python project as **time.time()**. I need to compare it with current timestamp in my java project as **System.Currenttimemillis()**. How to compare time in time.time()  and System.Currenttimemillis()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python returns the time in seconds since the Epoch as a floating number, while Java returns the amount of milliseconds since the epoch.

Just multiply the python result by 1000 and round down, to have a whole number which you can compare to the java timestamp.

If you're the owner/maintainer of both project, you might want to consider using text in the [ISO-8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) rather than numbers. Both languages have support for creating such a format based on the system time. Big advantage is that it's easier for *humans* to read this format ;)

Comment: Indeed, the ISO 8601 formats are much more sensible and practical for exchanging date-time info. For example: `2017-02-07T19:59:53Z` for the current moment in UTC. The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating strings of date-time values. With at least a couple dozen [epoch reference dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) in use and different granularities (whole seconds, millis, micros, nanos, etc.), count-from-epoch is clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

Note the differences: 
`time.time()` returns the time in **seconds** since the epoch as a floating point number, according to the timezone defined.
`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the time in **milliseconds** since the epoch as a long number, in UTC timezone.
So to compare the two you need to:

1. Convert the python time to UTC, e.g. by adding `time.timezone` to the result of `time.time()`
2. Convert the adjusted python time from seconds to milliseconds by multiplying by 1000 and rounding/ceil/floor the result.

After that you have both times in the same unit and timezone.